# Problems calling a SASS built-in function

Tags: css, sass

I have this fragment of SASS code:

```
@font-face {
  $rndnum: random(1000);
  font-family: myfont;
  src:url('fonts/myfont#{$rndnum}.svg')
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I need to put a random number after the name of the font, I know it seems stupid operation, but I need it. However the problem is that I get the following result:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myfont;
  src:url('fonts/myfontrandom(1000).svg') /* <== HERE */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

The function does not get called for some reason...
Where am I doing wrong?

### Something more...

I tried calling another function like `percentage`:

```
@font-face {
  $rndnum: percentage(0.2);
  ...
```

And it worked in that case... looks like it is not recognizing `random` as a valid function...

Comment: Are you running a version of Sass that *has* the `random()` function?

Comment: Well the problem s that this version of SASS has no random builtin function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just concatenating the string?

`src:url('fonts/myfont'+$rndnum+'.svg');`

And do you have the code for what `$rndnum` is being set as since this could also be a problem with how that variable is set.

Edit 1:

Your code works for me.  Do you just need the semi-colon after the `src` line?

What version of sass are you using?

I tried it [here](http://sassmeister.com/) and it seemed to work perfectly fine on Sass version 3.3.3 but not on version 3.2.15 (the two versions offered on that site).

Comment: Tried it... it doesn't work... :(

Comment: Post the code where you set the `$rndnum` variable.

Comment: See my edit, I think it might be your Sass version.

Comment: I think I have an older version of SASS...